# Content display on UITableViewCell (Nested NSArray &NSDictionary)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview, ios8

In my iPhone App, I display First Name & Last Name on the `UITableViewCell`. I used the following code. But I don't know how to display the content on `UITableViewCell` within a`UITableView`.

Response Data is:---

```
responseObject:
{
    data =     (
                (
                        {
                "created_date" = "2015-05";
                description = "Nice blogs...";
                "first_name" = John;
                id = 26;
                image = "profilethumb.png";
                "last_name" = Smith;
                "ref_id" = 16;
                reference = blog;
            }
        ),
                (
        )
    );
    status = success;
}
```

Below Code:---

```
        NSDictionary *dict=[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        strFirstName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"first_name"]];
        strLastName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"last_name"]];
        cell1.lblCommenterName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", strFirstName, strLastName];
```

How can I display User First Name & Last Name on the Cell.

Comment: Do you use a UITableView and it's DataSource and Delegate method?

Comment: I've added an answer, please check it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer code mentioned below:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Dequeue the cell.
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"idCellRecord";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    // You must have put an Identifier for the UITableViewCell in the Interface Builder. I've given it as "idCellRecord"
   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   }

    // Set the loaded data to the appropriate cell labels.
    NSDictionary *dict=[[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"data"];


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have implemented the following three essential UITableView DataSource Methods,

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1; // As you desire to have sections
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [arrayData count]; // number of objects within the array
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Dequeue the cell.
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"idCellRecord";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    // You must have put an Identifier for the UITableViewCell in the Interface Builder. I've given it as "idCellRecord"
   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   }

    // Set the loaded data to the appropriate cell labels.
    NSDictionary *dict=[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *strFirstName = [dict objectForKey:@"first_name"];
    NSString *strLastName  = [dict objectForKey:@"last_name"];

    [cell.textLabel setText:strFirstName];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:strLastName];

    return cell;
}
```

**Note:**

I've set the UITableView's UITableViewCell Style to "Subtitle" within the IB Tool.

I suggest you to read and get used to UITableViews within the following tutorials:

1. [MakeMeGeek](http://www.makemegeek.com/uitableview-example-ios/)
2. [AppCoda 1](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)
3. [AppCoda 2](http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/)

I hope this would be helpful to you to get done what you want.

Cheers!